# Sniff my wallet

Tags: transactions, wallet, automation

Is it possible to have some kind of transaction sniffer on my wallet?

Basically I would like to detect if a specific tx (coming from a specific program) arrives on my wallet, and in case it did, perform a specific action?

Comment: This is a really interesting idea. Kind of like, "push notifications" for your wallet?

Comment: Mmh not really. Im looking for a tx from a specific program for automatically send asset to an other wallet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you have 2 options. In the following I will assume you are working in TS, but analogous functions should also exist in APIs for languages.

1. The first one is a brute force approach, where you periodically load the confirmed signatures of your account using `getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2` (make sure to use the `until` parameter in the `ConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2Options` to load only the transaction signatures you have not checked yet). Then you need to load each of these transactions, e.g. via `getTransactions`, and check if they match your criteria.
2. A more elegant approach would be to use `onAccountChange` listener, however, this is possible only if the transaction makes a change to your account (i.e. your wallet is not a read-only account in the relevant transaction)

Comment: Can you tell me more about the listener? To be precise, I'm trying to listen to a PDA and if a tx arrives on this PDA, then I empty the PDA to another account automatically, without having to interact myself

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange. It should also not be too difficult to find working examples online.